# how to loop multipe variables in to one destination table using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have three variables

```
@Emp = 'Select EmpName from Employee',
@Department = 'Select DeptName from Department',
@Customer = 'Select Custname from Customer'
```

and I have destination table

Output :

```
  ID tbl_statement
  1   Select EmpName from Employee
  2   Select DeptName from Department
  3   Select Custname from Customer
```

[image]

How can I loop these three variables into destination table using SSIS

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean loop exactly?

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati those three variables how can I iterate into destination table

Answer (score 2):

I would propose you use an Execute SQL Task to store this data.

Given a target table such as the following

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SO_53235748
(
    ID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
,   tbl_statement nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
,   AsOfDate datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_dbo_SO_53235748 DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
```

We'll use an OLE DB Connection and parameterize a query like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SO_53235748(tbl_statement)
SELECT D.tbl_statement 
FROM 
(
    VALUES(?), (?), (?)
) D(tbl_statement);
```

The `?` is a placeholder in the OLE DB Connection manager syntax. In the preceding query, it expects 3 parameters. In the event you have more or fewer parameters, then you would need to add/remove elements in the fifth line.

In the parameters tab, we will map based on ordinal positions, zero based, our variables into the parameters

[image: Parameter mapping tab]

Answer (score -1):

Please try using For Each Variable looping in For Each Loop Task in SSis

Thanks